# Show that $\left\lVert T \right\rVert = \sqrt{r_{TT^*}}$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and $T \in L(X)$. Show that:
>
> $$ \left\lVert T \right\rVert = \sqrt{r_{TT^*}} $$
>
> where $r_{TT^*}$ is the spectral radius of $TT^*$.

I have already proved that $\left\lVert T \right\rVert^2 \geq r_{TT^*} $, but I am stuck on the reverse inequality.

What I did so far on the reverse inequality:

I concluded that $\left\lVert T \right\rVert ^2 = \left\lVert TT^* \right\rVert = \sup\{\left\langle TT^*x,x \right\rangle : \left\lVert x \right\rVert = 1\}$

and that

$$ r_{TT^*} \geq \left\lVert T \right\rVert ^2 $$ is equivalent to

$$ r_{TT^*} \geq \left\langle TT^*x,x \right\rangle \forall x \left\lVert x \right\rVert = 1$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $TT^*$ is selfadjoint and the spectral radius of a selfadjoint (even normal) operator equals its norm. If you don't know this (and may not use this), you maybe know Mazur's formula for the spectral radius?